# java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, websphere, websphere-liberty

I am working with an application, using Spring Boot + Spring Legacy (to be able to deploy the code in an older server running WebSphere).
I made a few tests in WebSphere Liberty, which ran just fine. However, when I deploy it on WebSphere Application Server, I got this errors:

```
     [12/13/17 7:56:47:170 MST] 00000012 SystemOut     O 07:56:47.169 [server.startup : 2] ERROR org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/com.org.entitymigration.EntityMigrationApplication]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/com.org.entitymigration.EntityMigrationApplication]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:168)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:124)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:140)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:116)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:84)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:87)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:267)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.AbstractRefreshableWebApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractRefreshableWebApplicationContext.java:134)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:230)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:156)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:48)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:1721)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.commonInitializationFinish(WebApp.java:388)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:299)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:100)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:166)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:732)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:617)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:376)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:668)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1146)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1320)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:611)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:945)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:759)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$3.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2082)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5397)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5485)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2087)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:434)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:377)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$300(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:123)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$CUInitializer.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:944)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:496)
        at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1662)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/com.ibm.entitymigration.EntityMigrationApplication]
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getInputStream(ServletContextResource.java:99)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:152)
```

I am pointing the ContextLoader to my Java Class that has the annotation @SpringBootApplication. These are my files:

**build.gradle**

```
group 'com.org.entitymigration'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java-library'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'war'

sourceCompatibility = 1.6
targetCompatibility = 1.6

compileJava {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
    options.fork = true
}

project.webAppDirName = 'WebContent'

mainClassName = 'com.org.entitymigration.Application'

sourceSets {
    main {
        java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src/main/resources']

    }
    test.java.srcDirs = ['src/test/java']
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

ext {
    spring_version = '1.5.9.RELEASE'
    thymeleaf_version = '3.0.9.RELEASE'
    thymeleaf_layout_version = '2.2.2'
}

configurations {
    providedRuntime
    compile.exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
}

dependencies {

    compileOnly group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'servlet-api', version: '2.5'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-legacy', version: '1.1.0.RELEASE'

    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: spring_version
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-actuator', version: spring_version
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf', version: spring_version
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-security' , version: spring_version
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-context', version: '4.3.13.RELEASE'

    compile group: 'org.thymeleaf', name: 'thymeleaf', version: thymeleaf_version
    compile group: 'org.thymeleaf', name: 'thymeleaf-spring4', version: thymeleaf_version
    compile group: 'nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf', name: 'thymeleaf-layout-dialect', version: thymeleaf_layout_version

    compile group: 'com.jcraft', name:'jsch', version:'0.1.52'

    testCompile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-test', version: spring_version


}

war {
    baseName = 'EntityMigration'
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>com.org.entitymigration.EntityMigrationApplication</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.boot.legacy.context.web.SpringBootContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>metricsFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>metricsFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServletDispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextAttribute</param-name>
            <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext.ROOT</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServletDispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>  

</web-app>
```

**EntityMigrationApplication.java (SpringBootApplication)**

```
package com.org.entitymigration;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class EntityMigrationApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(final SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(EntityMigrationApplication.class);
    }
}
```

**Configuration Class**

```
package com.org.entitymigration.conf;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;

import com.org.entitymigration.models.LoginInputParamFilter;
import com.org.entitymigration.services.EntityAuthenticationFailureHandler;
import com.org.entitymigration.services.EntityAuthenticationProvider;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter   {

     @Autowired
      private EntityAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

     @Bean
     public LoginInputParamFilter loginInputParamFilter()
                throws Exception {
         LoginInputParamFilter loginInputParamFilter = new LoginInputParamFilter();
         loginInputParamFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean());
            return loginInputParamFilter;
     }

     protected void configure(
        AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

          auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
      }

      protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
          http.formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .failureHandler(new EntityAuthenticationFailureHandler())
            .and()
            .logout()
            .permitAll();

        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/css/**", "/img/**", "/js/**")
            .permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated();


        http.authorizeRequests()
          .antMatchers("/resources/**","/rest/**","/login*", "/css/**", "/img/**", "/js/**","/error").permitAll()
          .anyRequest().authenticated()
          .and()
          .logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).logoutSuccessUrl("/login");

          http
          .addFilterBefore(loginInputParamFilter(), LoginInputParamFilter.class);
      }


       @Autowired
      public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
          auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);

      }


}
```

What am I missing for WebSphere Application Server?

Thank you.

Comment: For starters stop mixing Spring versions ... Spring Boot 1.5 has Spring 4.2 why are you including Spring 3.1 jars?

Comment: @M.Deinum I didn't understand about Spring Boot. The latest release was 1.5 (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web)
Regarding the Spring Context (which is using 3.1), you are right. I updated with the latest version (4.3.13.RELEASE), but the issue persists the same. I updated my question with the correction.

Comment: You are using Spring Boot which uses Spring 4.3 (typo on my side). You are mixing versions which is never a good idea. You don't need that dependency as it is already included in the other starters. Also you are using Spring Boot but don't use the Spring Boot plugin...

Comment: And please add the full stacktrace instead of a snippet.

Comment: @M.Deinum regarding the dependency that I don't need, do you mean Spring Context? Because without this dependence I got a ClassNotFoundException on WebSphere (not in Liberty).
Regarding the Spring Boot plugin, are you saying just to include "apply pugin: 'spring-boot' and the other dependencies should remain?

Comment: @M.Deinum I am updating with the full stacktrace

Comment: The `spring-context` is included by almost every starter but certainly the web starter. That basically is the whole point of the starters. You should use the spring boot plugin next to the war plugin.

Comment: @M.Deinum so, including spring boot plugin and removing the SpringContext dependency, correct?

Comment: Indeed (Spring boot does some additional things to your war to make it also executable and to manage dependencies).

Comment: The stacktrace indicates that you are loading a `ContextLoaderLIstener` somewhere. Which reacts to the `contextConfigLocation` property. That listener shouldn't be registered anywhere.

Comment: @M.Deinum I took off the listener tags, but the issue remains the same. I am updating my question.

Comment: That listener in your `web.xml` should stay. Something is also kicking in the `ContextLoaderListener` (read the stacktrace). Maybe you have it in a `@Configuration` class or something snuck in a `web-fragment.xml` or something else is going on.

Comment: @M.Deinum thank you for your hint. I checked my classes and files, but I still didn't find anything else related to ContextLoaderListener than listeners tags (web.xml). I included the unique **Configuration** file that I have, in case of I missed anything on this.